# Changing the value of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame, df

```
ID  year   Treat
1   2008     0
1   2009   2009
1   2010   2010
1   2011     0
2   2008     0
2   2009     0
2   2010     0
2   2011     0
```

I wanna generate a new variable new_treat:

```
ID  year   Treat  new_treat
1   2008     0       2009
1   2009   2009      2009
1   2010   2010      2009
1   2011     0       2009
2   2008     0        0
2   2009     0        0
2   2010     0        0
2   2011     0        0
```

I used the following code:

```
df['new_treat']= df.groupby(['id'])['treat'].shift(-1)

and

df['new_treat'] = df.groupby('id')['new_treat'].cummin()
```

It works with first two row but for the remaining I am getting zero.

Comment: You only have 2 non-zero entries in column `Treat`

Comment: For this data-frame I have only two non-zero but in my main data-frame there is number of nonzero values that I want to convert to beginning treatment year

Comment: The `cummin()` method works correctly. 0 is less than 2009. You may want to set the 0 values to NaN first.

Comment: Like @Arne suggests, keep blank entries as NaN rather than 0, then `.cummin()` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) instead of [cummin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html)

`cummin` is not working `from 3rd row` because value of `3rd row is 0 which is min compared to 2009` hence 3rd and 4th row for `id 1` is giving output as 0.

**Code**

```
df['new_treat']= df.groupby(['id'])['treat'].shift(-1)
df['new_treat'] = df.groupby('id')['new_treat'].transform('first').astype(int)
df
```

**Output**

```
    id  year    treat   new_treat
0   1   2008    0       2009
1   1   2009    2009    2009
2   1   2010    2010    2009
3   1   2011    0       2009
4   2   2008    0       0
5   2   2009    0       0
6   2   2010    0       0
7   2   2011    0       0
```